# Black screen on boot after installing AMDGPU

Tags: drivers, 16.04, radeon

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my computer.

I have an Hybrid video card, with IntelGraphics and AMD Radeon R7 M265. After some research, I decided to try the AMDGPU driver to use my Radeon instead of the IntelGraphics, but I hadn't realized that my video card is not compatible with this driver.

After the installation, I rebooted the system and now it wont start. All I can see after the bios screen is a black screen with a blinking white underline on the left top. Nothing works except when I press the power button and the ubuntu logo appears on the screen for a few seconds before the computer shuts down.

All I want is a way to uninstall this driver.

Answer (score 0):

Hold down shift key during boot, select advanced options, then select recovery mode. enter in root password when prompted.
The filesystem is in readonly mode, so do command:
mount -o remount,rw /
Now run the amdgpu-pro-uninstall command, which is in your path and you can use tab command name completion.
reboot

if you have problems interrupting grub with shift key, like i did, try to use an older ps2 connector keyboard. usb keyboards/mice are dicey during boot

Answer (score 0):

You are stuck at booting may be because, you installed `amdgpu` on your amd Radeon graphics machine. 
You will able to boot if you remove the amdgpu-pro.
Lets do it.

1. Power off your system.
2. Power on the system, at the same time press on <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.
3. Select advanced recovery option & enter your password
4. Then type the command:

   ```
   mount -o remount, rw /
   ```

   This will give read write permission.
5. Run command:

   ```
   amdgpu-pro-uninstall
   ```
6. This will uninstall `amdgpu-pro` from your system.
7. To shutdown system, run command: `poweroff` & then power on the system.